# Continuity of min function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I would like to ask a question about the continuity of this min function.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define
$$F(x):=\min\{f(t):t \in [-x,x]\}.$$

I believe that the function $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$
However, I do not know how to use the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition to show its continuity. Could somebody help me?

Thank you.
Masih

Answer (score 3):

Given $\epsilon > 0$ and $x$, we want to show that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|F(x)-F(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.

Since $[-x,x]$ is compact, the minimum is attained at some point(s) $t_0\in[-x,x]$.

Suppose first that $\pm x$ are not points of minimum, i.e. the minimum is attained strictly inside. Let $\delta$ be such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \frac12|f(x) - f(t_0)|$, by continuity of $f$. This $\delta$ will work for $F$ for any $\epsilon>0$ since $|F(x) - F(y)| = 0$ in this case.

Now suppose the minimum is attained at $\pm x$. Then again by continuity of $f$ at $\pm x$, find $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ if $|x-y|<\delta$. This $\delta$ will work as well.

Comment: I am not conviced with the implication  $|f(x)-f(y)| < \frac12|f(x) - f(t_0)|$, in the definition of the continuity,  $\epsilon$ doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: Here we have to prove continuity at the point $x$. The first case can ignore the given $\epsilon$ since the $\delta$ obtained will work for any $\epsilon$. I don't see a problem with the implication, since for a fixed $x$, $|f(x) - f(t_0)|$ is a fixed quantity.

Comment: Ok @Milind, the first case is now clear, would you explain more the second one. Thank you.

Comment: @hachem In the second case the minimum is at $\pm x$, so $F(x)=f(x)$ (or $-x$). So since we can find a neighbourhood around $\pm x$ such that $f(y)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $f(x)$ for all $y$ in the nbd, the same will be true of $F(y)$ and $F(x)$, which is what we want.

Comment: thank you @Milind, nice work !